# Manifold assumption when visualizing high dimensional dynamical systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, dynamical-systems, visualization

I come from a background in statistics, where we often visualize high dimensional data sets by projecting them onto lower dimensional subspaces. The most common example of this approach is Principal Components Analysis, but there is also Multi-dimensional Scaling, and other similar tools. The "Manifold Assumption" we make is that the data exist on some lower dimensional manifold--where the dimensionality of the manifold is much lower than the dimensionality of the dataset. This assumption does hold pretty well for real-world data sets where only a few dimensions exhibit substantial variation, and the remaining dimensions are highly correlated with these key dimensions.

Lately I have been looking more into the dynamical systems literature to round out some tools in my toolkit. While visualizing phase spaces and direction fields up to 3 dimensions is fine for textbooks, I was wondering what visualization methods work for higher dimensional dynamical systems? So if we have a large compartment model or such, what are the good ways to visualize the dynamics of such systems?

Hence to bring it back to my question, does this manifold assumption make sense for visualizing high dimensional dynamical systems? Can we project the dynamics of the system down to say 3 dimensions and then visualize the system's behavior there? Or are there other better ways to visualize the orbits and phase spaces of high-dimensional dynamical systems?

Comment: Great question, but it is very difficult to give a helpful answer. The key point seems seems to be "the remaining dimensions are highly correlated with these key dimensions", up to making it rigorous. And there is really nothing similar in dynamics, except partly in ergodic theory, via coupling, but really this is something different. So your question should instead be: can I really get good representation (whatever this means, in some rigorous way) by projecting?

Comment: @JohnB Thanks for your excellent points. I think the first question is how do app. math folks visualize high dimensional dynamical systems. So perhaps most folks look at summary plots--like a time series of counts that are the composite of a number of different input equations. But then to move backward from there to look at the contribution of the different dimensions to the overall result? Textbooks make it seem like the point is to show the different topological features--like a bifurcation, etc. But this idea may not work in high dimension where we can't visualize each dimension?

Comment: Or it could be that the topological features at the detailed equation level lead to some meso-level manifold structure that we can learn from and visualize? But like I said, I am still just getting into the dynamical systems literature, so just trying to reconcile the toy examples from books to real phenomena and models that are higher dimensional?

Comment: @JohnB I think mathematically there are some interesting approaches like spectral graph theory methods to look at clustering behavior in high dimension, where the affinity metric incorporates behavior over the total flow of the system. This might be able to pick out the relationship between lower level equations and some meso-level clustering behavior. Of course spectral graph methods have analogues with ergodic theory and percolation.